# SQLite: Divide value from one column based on criteria from other columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I have a table in SQLite3 with the following structure:

```
Date                    Category              Value
------------            --------------        -------------
20160101                A                     5
20160101                B                     3
20160102                A                     4
20160102                B                     2
20160103                A                     7
20160103                B                     3
20160104                A                     8
20160104                B                     1
```

My goal is to select values from the table so that for each date I divide the value of category A with the value of category B. I have exactly one value for each category for every date. I.e. the goal is to select two columns with these values:

```
Date                    NewValue(A/B)
------------            --------------
20160101                1.6667                     
20160102                2                     
20160103                2.3333                      
20160104                8
```

I have tried to solve this by creating a temporary table, but I get wrong values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using conditional aggregation or a `join`:

```
select t.date, ta.value / tb.value
from t ta join
     t tb
     on ta.date = tb.date and ta.category = 'A' and tb.category = 'B';
```

One caveat:  SQLite does integer division.  So, if the values are integers, you should use something like:

```
select t.date, ta.value * 1.0 / tb.value
```